# Redhat to Centos Restore

Tags: centos, redhat

I feel like this might be a noob question, but I just wanted to verify my suspicions.

I have a production environment that is hosted on a Redhat server. I have a copy of the site that is hosed on that server on my local machine, which is running CentOS.

Recently, I've been testing our backups to make sure everything is working properly (better to figure that out now than later). Backing up my dev environment and restoring it works perfectly fine, but when I pull a backup from prod and attempt to restore that on dev (so Redhat to Cent), my bin gets corrupted. IE, I can't use ls commands, can't reboot, and shutting down the server will cause the server to not load again.

My assumption is this is probably because the backup for my prod is from a Redhat server, and I'm attempting to load it onto a CentOS server. I wanted to make sure this was correct, as I know CentOS is supposed to be compatible with Redhat.

Edit: =================================
The backup consists of the entire server, not just the application itself. 
The backup up script tars each of the root folders using a command like:

```
tar --selinux --acls --xattrs  -cvf /opt/backup_box/$NOW/bin.tar /bin ;
```

the backups are stored in opt, which has it's contents tared in the same way, excluding the backup files.

Edit #2 ===================================
The versions are:
production: [image]

and target:
[image]

Comment: Exactly how are you backing up and restoring?

Comment: If this is what's happening, you're replacing far more than the copy of your site.  Without knowing what it is that you're actually replacing with your backups, all anyone can do here is guess.

Comment: @MichaelHampton made an edit explaining on how the files are being tared.

Comment: And how do you perform the restore? RHEL and Centos should be binary compatible but if you dump the contents of e.g. /bin over the existing content there is no telling what you would get. Do you restore /boot this way too? And if so do you recreate the grub config? It is not clear to me what you want to achieve with this kind of backup procedure. Most files in /bin etc. are part of rpm packages so I would not try to restore them this way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just untaring them using tar -C / -xvpf bin.tar . The idea is if the server completely dies on me, I need to be able to get the system up and running on another server. Is there a better way to restore the backups then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably not the best way to back up and restore a system. You should strive to only include *just* the items you need for a functioning site or application. Copying binaries and clobbering existing files is a pretty drastic approach.

The most important thing to check, though, is the specific versions and releases of your production and development servers:

Please provide the output of:

```
uname -a; cat /etc/issue
```

Compare the production server and your backup target server.

If the releases are clearly not of the same version, you may be running into issues that are the result of version or CPU architecture incompatibilities, and not anything inherently wrong with CentOS and Red Hat.

CentOS and RHEL are compatible across *like-versions* and architectures.

---

***Edit:*** Your systems are of different architectures. Your production system is 64-bit, while your target server is 32-bit. This won't work if you're intending to copy any executable (binary) files. If this is a web application, you may be able to get away with moving the contents of the web directories... but it really makes sense to have similar source/target systems.

[image]

Comment: See edit #2. Both are on CentOS v. 5.8 (Final), however, the linux versions are different, 2.6.18-406.el5 vs. 2.6.18-308.el5, would that make a difference?